# Errors in an Array Brackets?

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error in my code and I am not sure why. Part of the "average" method is underlined. The error reads: "This method must return a result of type double". When I add an additional closing bracket, the error on the method goes away but java immediately wants me to delete the bracket that I added. I thought maybe that was a clue there's something wrong with my brackets?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayPractice
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] array = new int[20];


    System.out.println("Please enter 20 numbers.");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

}

    public static double average(int [] array)
    {
        int average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
        average = ((array[i])/2);
        }
        System.out.print(average + " ");
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't declare a method inside another method.

Comment: That worked for getting rid of the errors in the name of the method, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your method is setup to return a double. You should rewrite the method to it returns the double or just set it to void.

**using void**

```
public static void average(int [] array)
{
    int average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
    average = ((array[i])/2);
    }
    System.out.print(average + " ");

}
```

**return double**

```
public static double average(int [] array)
{
    int average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
    average = ((array[i])/2);
    }
    System.out.print(average + " ");
    return average;    
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think You should Declare

> int Average=0; (As local Variable)
>   inside method body